# substitution $A \mapsto A + \delta_A$ with some operator $\delta_A$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request, sorting

I want my input letter $A B$ and substitute $A \mapsto A + \delta_A$ and $B \mapsto B+ \delta_B$ so that
\begin{align}
A B + BA \mapsto A B + B A +   \delta_A B +   \delta_B A
\end{align}
Here $\delta_B$ acting on nothing gives zero.

For example

\begin{align}
ABC &\mapsto (A + \delta_A )(B +\delta_B)(C+\delta_B) = ABC + \delta_A(BC) + A \delta_B(C) + \delta_A \delta_B C \\
&= ABC + (\delta_A B) C + B \delta_A C +  A \delta_B C + \delta_A \delta_B C  
\end{align}

Further I want to generalized this to $ABCD$ and so on.

Is mathematica have a function or substitution rules like the above?

Further I want to distinguish $\delta_A \delta_B C \neq \delta_B \delta_A C$. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities. Here is an ad-hoc proposal. It uses [transformation rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html) and [`**`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html). It is limited to what OP asked for. It would have to be extended to be of any practical use.

```
(* simplify expressions *)
simplify[expr_]:=expr//.{
   (a___)**(b_Plus)**(c___):>Map[a**#**c&,b],
   (a_?NumericQ*b_)**c_:>a*(b**c), (* <--- new *)
    ___**0**___->0,
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x_]:>x (* <--- new *)
};
    
(* perturb symbols *)
Format[delta[X_]] := Subscript["\[Delta]",X];
perturb[X_Symbol] := X + delta[X];
perturb[a_Plus] := Map[perturb, a]; (* <--- new *)
perturb[X_**Y_] := perturb[X]**perturb[Y];

(* code to remove rightmost deltas *)
removeRightmostDeltas[expr_]:=Module[{dummy},
    simplify[simplify[expr**dummy]/.{
       delta[_]**dummy->0}]/.{a___**dummy:>NonCommutativeMultiply[a]}]// simplify;

(* new *)
applyDelta[expr_]:=FixedPoint[simplify[#//.{
       delta[X_Symbol]**(Y:(_Symbol|delta[_][_Symbol])):>
          NonCommutativeMultiply[delta[X][Y]]+Y**delta[X]}]&,simplify[expr]];
```

For example

```
X**Y**Z//perturb//simplify
```

gives

[image]

And

```
X**Y**Z//perturb//applyDelta//removeRightmostDeltas
```

gives

[image]

I did not use `C` since it has built-in meaning.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer. But I have one more question, In your code individual $X**Y$, $Y**X$ works but $X**Y + Y**X$ do not work. How one can added $+$ operation in your code?

Comment: Furthermore it does not explicitly show $\delta_{X} (YZ)$, I want the form of $(\delta_{X}  Y) Z + Y \delta_{X}Z$. Maybe it need distribution of operators

Comment: @phy_math Hello. I added a rule, you can now use `X**Y+Y**X//perturb//simplify`. This code is very incomplete, you will have to add rules. Concerning your second question, you did not state in your post precisely what the algebraic nature of your symbols is supposed to be. I now understand from your examples that you are assuming that they satisfy some sort of product rule. I added a rule that might do what you want, but you will have to decide yourself. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the response! For the distribution propertly I got it but still I have a problem with addition! 

> X ** Y + Y ** X // perturb // applyDelta // removeRightmostDeltas

gives

> X ** Y + 2 X ** Subscript["\[Delta]", Y] + Y ** X + 
 2 Y ** Subscript["\[Delta]", X] + Subscript["\[Delta]", X][Y] + 
 Subscript["\[Delta]", Y][X]

which seems there is something wrong with addition operations.

Comment: @phy_math It would not say it was wrong, it just did not remove terms such as `2*(Y**delta[X])` and another rule was needed in `simplify`. If you want to do symbolic computation, learn about `FullForm` and reas [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html) in detail. If you do a larger calculation, you must plan more carefully than I did here. Perhaps also look into a package such as [NCAlgebra](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) but I have not used it.

Comment: thanks for the information!